# Webscraping: remove word if in first 20 characters of document?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a bunch of speeches from http://www.millercenter.org. I have the speeches scraped and formatted just how I want them, except for one small piece. Every document (all 911 of them) has the word 'transcript' at the beginning, and I don't want them in the document as I move forward with some NLP. I haven't been able to remove them, and I've tried both the `replace` and `remove` methods. I even tried extending my `find` method through the piece of HTML that says `<h2>Transcript</h2>` at the beginning of each document.

Here's a sample of what I'm looking at, document-wise:

```
transcript
to the senate and house of representatives
i lay before congress several dispatches from his
```

and

```
transcript
the period for a new election of a citizen to administer the executive government
```

Here's my code:

```
import urllib2,sys,os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,NavigableString
from string import punctuation as p
from multiprocessing import Pool
import re, nltk
import requests
reload(sys)

chester_url = 'http://millercenter.org/president/arthur/speeches/speech-3752'
chester_3752 = urllib2.urlopen(chester_url).read()
chester_3752 = BeautifulSoup(chester_3752)

# find the speech itself within the HTML
chester_3752 = chester_3752.find('div',{'id': 'transcript'},{'class': 'displaytext'})

# removes extraneous characters (e.g. '<br/>')
chester_3752 = chester_3752.text.lower()

# for further text analysis, remove punctuation
punctuation = re.compile('[{}]+'.format(re.escape(p)))

chester_3752 = punctuation.sub('', chester_3752)
chester_3752 = chester_3752.replace('—',' ')
chester_3752 = chester_3752.replace('transcript','')
```

Like I said, that `replace` method at the end doesn't seem to be working. Thoughts?

Comment: do the strings always start with `'transcript'`?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your problem is but when I ran this with python 3.4 and bs4 it removed "transcript" along with a bunch of punctuation.  (I took out a bunch of includes and changed `urllib2` to `urllib.request`)

```
import urllib.request
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import re
from string import punctuation as p

chester_url = 'http://millercenter.org/president/arthur/speeches/speech-3752'
chester_3752 = urllib.request.urlopen(chester_url).read()
chester_3752 = BeautifulSoup(chester_3752)

# find the speech itself within the HTML
chester_3752 = chester_3752.find('div',{'id': 'transcript'},{'class': 'displaytext'})

# removes extraneous characters (e.g. '<br/>')
chester_3752 = chester_3752.text.lower()

# for further text analysis, remove punctuation
punctuation = re.compile('[{}]+'.format(re.escape(p)))

chester_3752 = punctuation.sub('', chester_3752)
chester_3752 = chester_3752.replace('—',' ')
chester_3752 = chester_3752.replace('transcript','')

print(chester_3752)
```

Comment: Could it make a difference that I'm running Python 2.7?

Comment: They are different so it is possible, but it is odd that `chester_3752 = chester_3752.replace('—',' ')` works and `chester_3752 = chester_3752.replace('transcript','')` doesn't.  Another thing you might want to try is to put in another line after the last line as it seems strange that only the last line is not getting executed.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code, it works fine but there is a slight adjustment I'll recommend. Instead of using `replace` use [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) to be sure the string indeed starts with `transcript`. Replace will delete all occurences of transcript from the entire string but what you really need is to delete transcript when it's at the beginning of the string.

```
import urllib2
import sys
from string import punctuation as p
import re

reload(sys)

chester_url = 'http://millercenter.org/president/arthur/speeches/speech-3752'
chester_3752 = urllib2.urlopen(chester_url).read()
chester_3752 = BeautifulSoup(chester_3752)

# find the speech itself within the HTML
chester_3752 = chester_3752.find('div',{'id': 'transcript'},{'class': 'displaytext'})

# removes extraneous characters (e.g. '<br/>')
chester_3752 = chester_3752.text.lower()

# for further text analysis, remove punctuation
punctuation = re.compile('[{}]+'.format(re.escape(p)))

chester_3752 = punctuation.sub('', chester_3752)
chester_3752 = chester_3752.replace('-',' ')
print(chester_3752)

# chester_3752 = chester_3752.replace('transcript','') #avoid this as it will delete all instances of transcript in the string

if chester_3752.startswith("transcript"): #this ensures only transcript at the beginning of the string is deleted which is what you want
    chester_3752 =  chester_3752[10:].strip() 
print chester_3752
```

Comment: When I run that, I get an error in the `if` statement: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 61344: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: The if statment it's complaioning about is: `chester_3752 = chester_3752.replace('—',' ')` and not the one removing the `transcript` from the text.

Comment: I added `.encode('utf-8')`, and solved that problem. But it's still not removing 'transcript' for me. I don't believe there are any other characters before 'transcript', so it's not like we're missing anything prior to the word.

Comment: awesome, but I tried your code and it is removing transcript using the url in your example. Print the string out before and after removing `transcript` as i did and see what's there.